# Android NDK - Load texture from other thread

Tags: java, c, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I try to write loading screen for my Android NDK game project - to preload all textures.
If create texture in other thread, i get values like texture width set correctly, but get just black sprite instead of textured one, even if glGetError return 0. In same thread everything works ok, so assume there are no errors in sprite or texture code.

I think that is because i try to call opengl es 2.0 functions from another thread, without context provided by EGL. But how then get opengl es 2.0 context from EGL, which created in Java (Android) and bind it to use in opengl es 2.0 functions in native C?

**Java(Android)**

```
public class OGLES2View extends GLSurfaceView
{
 private static final int OGLES_VERSION = 2;

 public OGLES2View(Context context)
 {
  super(context);
  setEGLContextClientVersion(OGLES_VERSION);
  setRenderer(new OGLES2Renderer());
 }

private GLSurfaceView ogles2SurfaceView = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ogles2SurfaceView = new OGLES2View(this);
    setContentView(ogles2SurfaceView);
}
```

**C**

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef unsigned char bool;

typedef struct game_data
{
 bool loaded;
 tex* t;
}game_data;

static void* loader_thread_func(void* arg)
{
 JavaVM* jvm = get_java_vm(); //get java VM to detach in the end
 JNIEnv* env = get_jni_env(); //== attach current thread
 game_data* to_load = (game_data*) arg;
 to_load->t = malloc(sizeof(tex));
 set_tex(to_load->t,"textures/bonus.png");//textures width and height set correctly
 to_load->loaded = TRUE;
 (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
 return NULL;
}

void load_game_data(game_data* res)
{
 pthread_t loader_thread;
 pthread_create(&loader_thread, NULL, loader_thread_func, res);
}

/*in render manager file*/
static game_data* g_d = NULL;

/*in onInit func*/
g_d = malloc(sizeof(game_data));
g_d->loaded = FALSE;
load_game_data(g_d);

/*in onDraw function*/
 if(g_d->loaded)
 /*draw sprite*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call OpenGL ES functions from another thread you have to create a shared OpenGL ES context between 2 threads.

There is an easier solution - send the event to the thread that owns the OpenGL ES context to update the texture as soon as it is loaded in the second thread.

Answer (score -1):

Android does not support shared OpenGL contexts, so you must use the main context to create the texture.  You can load the texture data on the background thread, but the creation of the texture with that data must be done with the main context.  Sergey's suggestion of sending the event to the main thread after loading the texture data is the correct approach on Android.

Comment: Android certainly does support shared contexts, since GLES20. Anyone stuck using a GLSurfaceView has to use shared contexts to access GLES30 functions (like bit blitting). With GLES30,  real buffer objects can be packed, and used to transfer textures asynchronously to the GL thread.